# What's the most foolproof way to pass a Boolean value to a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, boolean

When building a jQuery plugin that is supposed to be passed a Boolean value, what's the most *fool-proof* way of converting the input to a Boolean in a user-friendly way?

To be more precise: I am afraid of the case that people might pass a String of `'false'` (instead of a plain `false`) and therefore a simple conversion of `!!option` or `Boolean(option)` will return the "wrong" value (`!!'false'` is `true`).

At the moment I am checking my `var option` like this:

```
if (typeof(option) != 'boolean'){
    if (option === 'false'){
        option = false; //fake false
    } else {
        option = !!option; //everything else is converted as truthy / falsy in a standard manner  
    }
}
```

but I was wondering if there is a more elegant and concise way to do so, or is this just the way that JavaScript handles this?

Comment: "A common mistake that people make when trying to design something completely foolproof is to underestimate the ingenuity of complete fools." -Douglas Adams

Comment: @j08691 good thing is that I'm a fool myself so prepare for a lot of ingenuity :P Other than that, replace "fool-proof" by "user-friendly"

Comment: Don't try to "fix" such things.  Designing an API to coddle incompetent programmers is generally a terrible idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most fool proof way, if you are afraid of such input, is to do just

```
if (typeof(option) != 'boolean')
    console.error('Function X expects a Boolean.');
```

Look at the solution you have now, you didn't take into  account `0` or `1`. Or what about `no` or `yes`?

Strings and Integers aren't meant to be used as Booleans; so, there is no need to parse them.

---

Take a look at high quality / usage JS frameworks, **they don't do this.** *Why should you?*

Comment: Well, in case the docs state "pass a Boolean" and someone will pass his dogs' name I could live with things going wrong, so I was actually just looking for a way to circumnavigate `'false'` problems - other than that you are totally right.

Comment: @m90: How did you determine that to be a problem?

Comment: @TomWijsman `false` is not considered falsy, while `true` is truthy and it's a common mistake to enclose params with quotes.

Comment: @Christoph programmers who make such mistakes need to learn that they are mistakes. An API that treated a non-empty string as `false` would be surprising indeed to an experienced programmer.

Comment: @Christoph: Indeed, by working this way one introduces the behavior we don't want.

Comment: I do totally agree that this is 100% correct in theory (and also I guess I'll now opt for the error throwing instead of trying to "correct" things that aren't correct), but I also guess you cannot shut your eyes and pretend that only pros will use the things you build (especially with jQuery plugins). I do know a lot of people who build websites that will break after 6 months and then complain that the non-pro editor "messed things up". I just don't want to be one of those guys....

Comment: @m90: People that use your plugin need to *adhere to the contract* you specify in your documentation; if they don't then it's their fault, not yours. Asserts (or errors) can help you to catch such errors, but you shouldn't go further than that to introduce behavior that isn't specified in your documentation. You could of course go and enumerate what you understand as a Boolean in your documentation, but if you think that way for everything then you're going to have to implement a lot more code and document a lot more. Don't over-think your library, or it can become bad in other ways...

Comment: @TomWijsman "you shouldn't go further than that to introduce behavior that isn't specified in your documentation" : 100% convinced, case closed! Thanks for the input

Answer (score 4):

I would do this.

```
var result = ( userInput === true );
```

The only way that this result will return true is if the type if a boolean and the value is true. Otherwise everything else is false.
Don't waste your time trying to fix other's mistakes.

But.... if you have a lot of time on your hands, then try this.

```
var getBooleanValue = function( userInput ){
    if( !userInput ){
        return false;
    }
    var boolNames = {
        'true':1, 'yes':1,
        'false':0,'no':0,
        'yourMoM':1
    };
    return (userInput in boolNames && !!boolNames[ userInput ])|| ( userInput === true );
};
var tests = [
    [ true, true ],
    [ 'true', true ],
    [ 'yes', true ],

    [ false, false ],
    [ 'false', false ],
    [ 'no', false ]
];
var runTest = function( tests ){
    var i = tests.length;
    while( i-- ){
        if( getBooleanValue(tests[i][0]) !== tests[i][1] ){
            throw new Error( "Test error: getBooleanValues( " + tests[i][0] + ") should return " + tests[i][1] );
        }
    }
};
runTest( tests );
```

Comment: +1 for proper testing. -1 for a post-decrement which creates a temporary value on each iteration. +1 for one-liner.

Comment: `var boolNames = {
        'true':1, 'yes':1,
        'false':0,'no':0,
        'yourMoM':this.yes
    };` is invalid.  You cannot use `this` in an object literal.  Otherwise, nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

I would do something like this:

```
var falsey = ["0", "", "false", "null", "undefined", "NaN"];
var isFalse = false;

for(var i = 0, len = falsey.length; i < len; i++){
    if(options + "" == falsey[i]){
        isFalse = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

What I did is to stringize both the `options` and the falsey values `0, "", false, null, undefined, NaN`

This will detected them regardless of what they were (technique similar to uppercase both the search word and the comparing word)

Because the list is short, you could also do it with switch cases or else ifs

Comment: Feeding programmers that make mistakes is a very bad idea. A `O(n)` for loop and array lookup, *really?*

Comment: @TomWijsman true, maybe switch cases or else ifs would be faster

Comment: @ajax333221 or.. you could just use a hash table which has an average of O(1 + n/k)

Comment: @LarryBattle thanks for your comment/answer, +1 for both. I really learned something valuable :)

Comment: @LarryBattle hi again, I need your special powers to test the performance, because I am doing something wrong http://jsperf.com/hashtablevsarraylookup

Comment: You should make a new question instead of making a long comment thread about a different problem.

Comment: @ajax333221 The 'in' keyword and most object methods are slow in javascript. Arrays are usually faster.

Comment: @LarryBattle but they can't be slow http://www.kirupa.com/html5/hashtables_vs_arrays.htm I want to improve plx tell me how to use O(1 + n/k) :(